# Calculating p99/p95 of an API

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

My target is to display the p99/p95 metices of an API.
Here is my code:

```
@Bean
Summary getSummary(){
    return  Summary.build()
            .name("requests_latency_seconds")
            .help("Request latency in seconds.")
            // 0.5 quantile (median) with 0.01 allowed error
            .quantile(0.5, 0.01)
            .quantile(0.7, 0.01)
            // 0.95 quantile with 0.005 allowed error
            .quantile(0.95, 0.005)
            .quantile(0.99, 0.002)
            // ...
            .register(registry.getPrometheusRegistry());
}
```

Here is the test api

```
    @GetMapping("/helloThree")
public String helloThree(){

    Summary.Timer requestTimer = summary.startTimer();
    try {
        //100 200ms 打点
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    };
    requestTimer.observeDuration();
    return "Three!";
}
```

I've got multiple request latency metices data. I need to calculate the P99/P95 latency metrics for this API.

Here's the sample time series data:

```
requests_latency_seconds{quantile="0.5",} 0.0999916
requests_latency_seconds{quantile="0.7",} 0.1001576
requests_latency_seconds{quantile="0.95",} 0.1002467
requests_latency_seconds{quantile="0.99",} 0.1002467
requests_latency_seconds_count 5.0
requests_latency_seconds_sum 0.49920190000000003
```

PromQl I have so far:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(requests_latency_seconds{instance=~"$instance",application="$application",uri!~".*helloThree.*"}[1m])) by (le,uri))
```

However, the grafana shows no data at all. Can a PromQL expert here please help!

I was expecting the grafana can show p55/p99 metices data

Answer (score 2):

The `requests_latency_seconds` is a [summary metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#summary). It already provides the pre-calculated percentiles as you mentioned in the question. So, just specify the needed percentile in [label filters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering). For example the following PromQL query returns p95 for this metric:

```
requests_latency_seconds{quantile="0.95"}
```

Note that [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile) function must be used only with [histogram metrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram). It cannot be be used with `summary metrics`.